# Flutter debugging release mode, enable logs in release mode

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, release-mode, flutter-debug

I know based on documentation that

> Debugging information is stripped out.
> Debugging is disabled.

But can we somehow force to print logs, or maybe debug in release mode? "production app"
I'm using Android Studio.

For example while developing android app in AS we are able to print logs

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check all available devices run `flutter devices`

Then run the below command to run the app in release mode with the logs

`flutter run -d [deviceID] --release`

Answer (score 16):

Plug your phone (if it is the case) on your computer and type on terminal:

```
$ flutter logs
```

You should be able to choose the device you want to see logs.

Comment: This does not show anything for me.
`flutter logs
Showing ELE L29 logs:`

Comment: FWIW, looks like the behavior here is that it tails the logs, so you'd run this command, choose the device you want, then run your app on that device

Answer (score 4):

To display information that you would like to be visible in release mode ('production code') of your flutter app, simply use `print()` method. For info you want to hide in console log use `debugPrint()`.

Maybe this part of [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging) will help.

Comment: using pring or debugprint in release (flutter run --release) on ios does not log anything

Answer (score 1):

If you are using logger package, you must add a permissive filter, since the default one only prints on debug:

```dart
class PermissiveFilter extends logfilter {
  @override
  bool shouldlog(LogEvent event) => true;
}

var logger = logger(filter: PermissiveFilter());
```