# http post request not working in apk but working with debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a CRUD application. **Problem :** everything works perfectly when I debug my application on the emulator or physical device but when I create APK and run it on mobile all request works fine except post request.

As I search I have given internet permission already.

**My post request**

```
await http.post(
  Uri.parse('https://myap'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
  },
  body: jsonBody,
).then(
  (response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('home');
    }
 
  },
).catchError(
  (e) {
        print(e);
  },
);
```

**Get function fine on apk, emulator, and physical devices.**

```
 Future fetchFeed() async {
    await http.get(Uri.parse('https://myapi'), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    }).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }).catchError(
      (e) {
          print(e);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you see the error?

Comment: have you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your androidmaifest.xml  ?

Comment: yes, I did, but even if the problem is with the internet permission it should not run other HTTP request like get,put,delete. it runs all other requests well except .post

Comment: i think we need the `error` .  please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517713/12838877

 to show the logs in release mode

Answer (score 1):

If it works properly on debug mode but not in release(apk) mode, there's chances of lack of internet permissions in `manifest.xml` file.

Android apps must declare their use of the internet in the Android manifest (AndroidManifest.xml), at `"android\app\src"`:

Here you will find 3 folders, add this snippet to `AndroidManifest` in each folder.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `jsonBody`. It does not consider it as map so it is still trying to send the request,

Try to put :

```
    body : { 
       'key1' : '${jsonBody['key1']}',
       'key2' : '${jsonBody['key2']}',
       'key3' : '${jsonBody['key3']}',
   
    }
```

It will work then you can leave it or you can search what is the problem in jsonBody